# Can't fully delete apps on Android?

Tags: uninstallation

Pokemon Go is encountering bugs on my install, and I want to completely uninstall it and reinstall, but Android won't let me. After uninstalling, the icon disappears and the app appears to be gone, but if I click "Install" on Google Play, the game immediately reappears on my device without downloading, meaning that Android is still keeping the entire app on my device and is not letting me reinstall to fix the issues. I can't find where on my device the actual files are kept. I tried deleting the leftover files under Android/obb, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling from an APK that I found, but that doesn't work, because the game is still installed. I tried resetting and clearing my cache multiple times.

I know that reinstalling will fix the issue with the bugs, too, because I was able to install the game on my secure folder profile, and it worked perfectly. If Android would just allow me to delete the app, I wouldn't have wasted the last five hours of my life.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Application manager > Pokemon Go > CLEAR CACHE and CLEAR DATA, FORCE STOP and then UNINSTALL.

Reinstall it again and it should work fine.

Comment: After clearing data there's no need to do anything else. The system automatically shuts down the app and clears its cache before clearing its data, and re-installing an app basically does nothing other than that.